# How to change interpolation to constant and set motion blur position to start of frame?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, motion-blur, interpolation

I encountered a problem where using motion blur in Eevee causes a render glitch when a Child Of Constraint keyframes are animated.

Looking into the problem I found this bug report: https://developer.blender.org/T73756
It was suggested to "change interpolation to constant and set motion blur position to start of frame you can work around this issue."